# Clickhandler doesn't fire

Tags: java, gwt

I have a problem with `ClickHandler` in my project using GWT.

In the title of dialog box I want to insert a new button.

1. I created a new insert method: `addToTitle(...)`.
2. I added `ClickHandler` to the button

Problem: click event by button doesn't fire. Why?

Here is my code:

```
DialogBox dialog = new DialogBox();

Button button = new Button("A new Button");

       button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
            {
                Window.alert("yuhuhuhu");

            }
        });

dialog.addToTitle(button);
```

code (extracted from the comments section) :

```
public class PlentyDialogWindow extends DialogBox { 
    private FlowPanel captionPanel = new FlowPanel(); 
    public Widget closeWidget = null; 
    private boolean closeOnEscKey = false; 
    private FlowPanel titleContentWrapper = new FlowPanel(); 
    public PlentyDialogWindow(boolean isModal) { 
        super( false, isModal); 
        this.addStyleName("DialogBox"); 
        this.getElement().setId("DialogBoxId"); 
        this.setAnimationEnabled(true); 
        this.closeWidget = generateCloseButton(); 
    }

    public void setCaption( String txt,Widget w) { 
        captionPanel.setWidth("100%"); 
        this.addCaption(txt); 
        this.titleContentWrapper.getElement().getStyle().setDisplay(Display.INLINE_BLOCK); 
        captionPanel.add(this.titleContentWrapper); 
        FlowPanel widgetWrapper = new FlowPanel(); 
        widgetWrapper.add(w); 
        widgetWrapper.addStyleName("PlentyPopupCloseIconWrapper"); 
        captionPanel.add(widgetWrapper); 
        captionPanel.addStyleName("Caption"); 
        Element td = getCellElement(0,1); 
        td.setInnerHTML(""); 
        td.appendChild(captionPanel.getElement()); 
    }

    /** * * @param w */ public void addToTitle(Widget w) { 
        this.titleContentWrapper.add(w); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure the Bug is inside the addToTitle(). Please show that code.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Does the `addToTitle(...)` function by any chance convert the widget added to a HTML string (thus removing any chance for GWT to maintain references to the handler)? We really need to see your `DialogBox` class to help. Cheers,

Comment: thanks for your answers! 

the addToTitle(...)-function only insert the new widget into the the title od dialogbox. 
<code>
public void addToTitle(Widget w)
 {
  this.titleContentWrapper.add(w);
 }
</code>  

And the dialogBox is a class of GWT.

Comment: How do you add a widget to the `DialogBox` title? The `.get/.setTitle()` methods work with `String`'s and if "just" cast your widget to a string you will get the HTML and no handler - cf. my answer above. We *really* need to see the `addToTitle()` code.

Comment: "`this.titleContentWrapper`"??? The GWT `DialogBox`doesn't have an `addToTitle()` method, so your comment doesn't add up. Paste *your* `DialogBox` class or whatever you have into the question, please.

Comment: we want to insert a button into the title of DialogBox ( not only text). That's why i create the addToTitle()-function.   <code>
public void addToTitle(Widget w)
 {
  this.titleContentWrapper.add(w);
 }
</code>

Comment: I'll ask again, for the last time: 1) What type is `this.titleContentWrapper` and where does it come from 2) will you paste the entire class(es)?

Comment: the function addToTitle(...) insert only the new widget button into the title of DialogBox. After that i see the new button at the top of dialogBox but the clickEvent of the button don't fire

Comment: private FlowPanel titleContentWrapper = new FlowPanel();

Comment: the class has 500 code rows. Can i insert it here? sorry, i am new here

Comment: Let me venture a guess here: The `FlowPanel` gets added to the `DialogBox` title on the lines of: `dialog.setTitle( titleContentWrapper + "" )`? If so, see my original answer. If you are unable to extract the relevant parts of your 500-line class, you're going to find it difficult to get help here. Cheers,

Comment: i try to write some code from my class:

public class PlentyDialogWindow extends DialogBox
{
 
 private FlowPanel captionPanel = new FlowPanel();
 
 
 public Widget closeWidget = null;
 
 private boolean closeOnEscKey = false;
 
 
 private FlowPanel titleContentWrapper = new FlowPanel();

 public PlentyDialogWindow(boolean isModal)
 {
 
  
  super( false,
         isModal);
 
  
  this.addStyleName("DialogBox");
  
this.getElement()
    .setId("DialogBoxId");
  
  
  this.setAnimationEnabled(true);
  
  
  this.closeWidget = generateCloseButton();
 }

Comment: /**
  * 
  * @param w
  */
 public void addToTitle(Widget w)
 {
  this.titleContentWrapper.add(w);
 }

Comment: Edit your question instead of pasting in comments.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is a bit tricky.

```
public class PlentyDialogWindow extends DialogBox {

    /* 
     * Create custom inner class extending `FlowPanel`. You need it only
     * to make `onAttach` and `onDetach` methods be visible to wrapping 
     * class (e.g. your `PlentyDialogWindow` class).
     */
    static class MyCaptionPanel extends FlowPanel {

        @Override
        protected void onAttach() {
            super.onAttach();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDetach() {
            super.onDetach();
        }
    }

    /* 
     * `PlentyDialogWindow`'s field `captionPanel` will be an instance of 
     * this class.
     */
    private MyCaptionPanel captionPanel = new MyCaptionPanel();


    /*
     * ... leave the rest of your class untouched ...
     */


    /*
     * Finally, overwrite `PlentyDialogWindow`'s `onAttach` and `onDetach` 
     * methods to invoke `captionPanel`'s corresponding methods:
     */
    @Override
    protected void onAttach() {
        super.onAttach();
        captionPanel.onAttach();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        captionPanel.onDetach();
    }
}
```

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

If your only problem is ClickHandler not being called try using addDOMHandler instead of addClickHandler

```
yourWidget.addDomHandler(new ClickHandler() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {


  }
},ClickEvent.getType());
```